# Convert bitmap to binary values

Tags: matlab, bitmap, binary

I would like to convert a bitmap file into an array consisting of binary values; however when I use this script:

```
arr=imread('sample.bmp');
arrBin=cell(1140,912,3);
for i=1:1140
    for j=1:912
        for k=1:3
            arrBin(i,j,k)=dec2bin(arr(i,j,k));
        end;
    end;
end;
```

the debug info shows this:

```
Conversion to cell from char is not possible.

Error in imgProc (line 9)
            arrBin(i,j,k)=dec2bin(arr(i,j,k));

>>
```

Is there anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution going to be very slow on big images. You better do something like this:

```
I=imread('sample.bmp');
A=dec2bin(I,8);%8bit
% this is how you index to array
i=5;j=35;ch=2;
pixel=A(sub2ind(size(I),i,j,ch),:)
```

Comment: Thumbs up.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [content indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#zmw57dd0e30216) with `{}` in order to place the string values from [`dec2bin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) into your cell array `arrBin`, like so:

```
arrBin{i,j,k} = dec2bin(arr(i,j,k));
```

Comment: Thank you so much;